# Inserting the content of an html page into a split

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page (firstpage.html) divided into two parts; one split on the left and one split on the right.

I would like to add the content of a second html page (secondpage.html) on the right split, then through the appropriate div.

For example if I have the div shown below:

```html
<div hr class="horiz">

        <div class="split left">
            <div class="centered">
            
            <!-- here is the code that "fills" the left split -->

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="split right">
            <div class="centered">

            <!--Here I would like to add the entire content of the secondpage.html html page -->
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: So what is preventing you from adding that content?

Comment: I did not understand how to do it, because in the html page (in second page.html) I pass to the url of the query parameters